# String concatenation with string literal and non string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, string-literals, variable-declaration

I want to understand what the following declaration means:

```cpp
constexpr auto type = u"bluetooth-opp-transfer-complete"_ns;
```

I know `constexpr` evaluates things at compile time, but what does `u` mean here? Also will _ns gets appended here? if yes then how cause _ns is not defined anywhere.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 1):

The u makes it a UTF-16 string literal. For more options see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), for example.